Github Actions: PyInstaller builds broken .exe
.yaml file
name: Package offlineEditor.exe
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: ["master", "main"]

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ['windows-latest', 'ubuntu-latest']
        python-version: ["3.10"]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
        
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        name: Checkout

      - uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        name: Setup Python
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix['python-version'] }}

      - name: Refresh data folder from source
        run: |
          rm -r compiled/editor/data
          cp -r src/data/ compiled/editor/data/

      - name: Build Executables (Windows)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'windows-latest' }}
        run: |
          Remove-Item -Path "compiled/editor/offlineEditor-windows.exe" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
          pip install pyinstaller
          pyinstaller --distpath compiled/editor --workpath /tmp/win/ --name offlineEditor-windows.exe --clean --icon="src/data/icon.ico" -F src/main.py

      - name: Upload Artifacts (Windows)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'windows-latest' }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: offlineEditor-artifact-windows
          path: compiled/editor/offlineEditor-windows.exe

      - name: Build Executables (Linux)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
        run: |
          rm -rf compiled/editor/offlineEditor-linux.sh
          pip install pyinstaller
          pyinstaller --distpath compiled/editor --workpath /tmp/linux/ --name offlineEditor-linux.sh --clean --icon="src/data/icon.ico" -F src/main.py

      - name: Upload Artifacts (Linux)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest' }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: offlineEditor-artifact-linux
          path: compiled/editor/offlineEditor-linux.sh

      - name: Commit Artifacts
        if: always()  # Stellen sicher, dass dieser Schritt immer ausgeführt wird
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "github-actions@github.com"
          git config --global user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git pull origin main  # Aktualisieren Sie zuerst lokale Änderungen
          git add .
          git commit -m "Automated build"
          git push origin main


I try to autobuild .exe's or .sh from a repo with python-code.
The exact same command used to build the windows-executable works on my powershell perfectly fine and produces a ~8mb big .exe
The one from the github-action is 6,8mb and doesnt run.
Also for Linux i need to set chmod +x and so on aswell i suppose? Or do people need to do that theyre own.
The goal is to get 2 executable's beeing able to be ran under theyre respective OS.

I have encountered a similar issue before. I was able to solve it using one of the following methods (1 or 2):

Set the PYTHONPATH.
In the step where you run PyInstaller, try setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable as follows:
- name: Build Executables (Windows)
  env: 
    PYTHONPATH: ${{ github.workspace }}
  run: |
    pyinstaller src/main.py


Install your custom package.
Use setup.py or another method to make your custom package installable. Then, during the installation of dependencies, use the command pip install -e ..
Here's an example:
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install pyinstaller
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install -e .



Please note that the original response was written in Japanese, and the author used translation tool for translation. Therefore, the accuracy of the translation may vary.
